# Queries regarding celery scalability

Tags: celery

I have few questions regarding celery. Please help me with that.

1. Do we need to put the project code in every celery worker? If yes, if I am increasing the number of workers and also I am updating my code, what is the best way to update the code in all the worker instances (without manually pushing code to every instance everytime)?
2. Using `-Ofair` in celery worker as argument disable prefetching in workers even if have set `PREFETCH_LIMIT=8 or so`?
3. IMPORTANT: Does rabbitmq broker assign the task to the workers or do workers pull the task from the broker?
4. Does it make sense to have more than one celery worker (with as many subprocesses as number of cores) in a system? I see few people run multiple celery workers in a single system.
5. To add to the previous question, whats the performance difference between the two scenarios: single worker (8 cores) in a system or two workers (with concurrency 4)

Please answer my questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

> Do we need to put the project code in every celery worker? If yes, if I am increasing the number of workers and also I am updating my code, what is the best way to update the code in all the worker instances (without manually pushing code to every instance everytime)?

Yes. A celery worker runs your code, and so naturally it needs access to that code. How you make the code accessible though is entirely up to you. Some approaches include:

- Code updates and restarting of workers as part of deployment

  If you run your celery workers in kubernetes pods this comes down to building a new docker image and upgrading your workers to the new image. [Using rolling updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) this can be done with zero downtime.
- Scheduled synchronization from a repository and worker restarts by broadcast

  If you run your celery workers in a more traditional environment or for some reason you don't want to rebuild whole images, you can use some central file system available to all workers, where you update the files e.g. syncing a git repository on a schedule or by some trigger. It is important you restart all celery workers so they reload the code. This can be done by [remote control](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-control).
- Dynamic loading of code for every task

  For example in  [omega|ml](https://github.com/omegaml) we provide lambda-style serverless execution of 
  arbitrary python scripts which are dynamically loaded into the worker process. 
  To avoid module loading and dependency issues it is important to keep `max-tasks-per-child=1` and use the prefork pool. While this adds some overhead it is a tradeoff that we find is easy to manage (in particular we run machine learning tasks and so the little overhead of loading scripts and restarting workers after every task is not an issue)

> Using -Ofair in celery worker as argument disable prefetching in workers even if have set PREFETCH_LIMIT=8 or so?

-O fair stops workers from prefetching tasks unless there is an idle process. However there is a [quirk with rate limits](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/e826729386aaf2b1f36b0d21591f9e71) which I recently stumbled upon. In practice I have not experienced a problem with neither prefetching nor rate limiting, however as with any distributed system it pays of to think about the effects of the asynchronous nature of execution (this is not particular to Celery but applies to all such such systems).

> IMPORTANT: Does rabbitmq broker assign the task to the workers or do workers pull the task from the broker?

Rabbitmq does not know of the workers (nor do any of the other broker supported by celery) - they just maintain a queue of messages. That is, it is the workers that pull tasks from the broker.

A concern that may come up with this is *what if my worker crashes while executing tasks*. There are several aspects to this: There is a distinction between a *worker* and the *worker processes*. The worker is the single task started to consume tasks from the broker, it does not execute any of the task code. The task code is executed by one of the worker processes. When using the prefork pool (which is the default) a failed worker process is simply restarted without affecting the worker as a whole or other worker processes.

> Does it make sense to have more than one celery worker (with as many subprocesses as number of cores) in a system? I see few people run multiple celery workers in a single system.

That depends on the scale and type of workload you need to run. In general CPU bound tasks should be run on workers with a concurrency setting that doesn't exceed the number of cores. If you need to process more of these tasks than you have cores, run multiple workers to scale out. Note if your CPU bound task uses more than one core at a time (e.g. as is often the case in machine learning workloads/numerical processing) it is the total number of cores used per task, not the total number of tasks run concurrently that should inform your decision.

> To add to the previous question, whats the performance difference between the two scenarios: single worker (8 cores) in a system or two workers (with concurrency 4)

Hard to say in general, best to run some tests. For example if 4 concurrently run tasks use all the memory on a single node, adding another worker will not help. If however you have two queues e.g. with different rates of arrival (say one for low frequency but high-priority execution, another for high frequency but low-priority) both of which can be run concurrently on the same node without concern for CPU or memory, a single node will do.